# CSS image resize distortion

Tags: css, image, resize

The images resize proportionally when they are less than 400px and stop scaling vertically at 400px, but the width continues to scale (thus distorting the image). Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
#gallery{
    height:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    max-height:800px;
    min-width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
#gallery .section {
    height:80%;
    min-height:400px;
    max-height:800px;
}
#gallery .section img{
    height:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    max-height:800px;
    width:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="section">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The distortion occurs when larger than 800px as well.

Comment: Remove `min-height:400px;` and `max-height:800px;` from `#gallery .section img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```css
#gallery {}

#gallery .section {}

#gallery .section img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Samsung-Galaxy-6-3-sample-image-3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

You've made some mistakes there:

1. To use "height: 100%" you must have "height: 100%" on html and body tags;
2. To set width/height of an element you have to convert it in a block or an inline-block;
3. "text-align: center" will center the inline elements; to center blocks use "margin: 0 auto";

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

To maintain aspect ratio you have to let height or width lead - and the other be auto.

Your rules are fighting each other.

I suggest using a wrapper for the image.

```css
.image-w {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.image-w img {
  display: block;
  /*for many reasons - but mainly to get rid of the little margin-bottom that happens by default */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-w">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately... putting this code into a so-snippet rearranges the order of importance. : /